# Is such participle clause reducing usage constrained to only past tense?

Tags: american-english, participles, present-participles, participle-clauses

As I saw on a grammar website, "She went into the home **and left** her shoes" equals "She went into the home, **leaving** her shoes".  Can this usage also be used with other tenses? Like future tense, present perfect tense, etc..

P.S. I mean, does the sentence "she has been working AND WRITING composion in her office" equal "she has been working, WRITING composition in her office".  .... and does "I will pay for it AND GIVE SOME PAMPHLET to you" equal "I will pay for it, GIVING SOME PAMPHLET to you"...etc.

[Here is the source](http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses) that describes an action that happens just before another action.

Comment: *"She went into the home and left her shoes"* **does not** equal *"She went into the home, leaving her shoes"* Is the question still valid?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the website you mentioned?

Comment: http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses check it out

Comment: see this part "an action that happens just before another action"

Answer (score 1):

The section of [the source](http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses) to which you pointed (*an action that happens just before another action*), has the participle clause and the main clause reversed.  If you apply the same reasoning to your sentence, it ought to have been

> **Leaving her shoes**, she went into the home.  *equals*
>   She left her shoes **and** went into the home.

In your first sentence the act of `leaving her shoes` ***is placed after*** the act of `going into the home` (connected with 'and'):

> She went into the home **and** left her shoes.

which suggests, according to the website, that it could be written as

> **Going** into the home, she left her shoes.

So, to answer your original question, no, those are **not** equivalent as far as the explanation "*action happens just before another action*" is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, English does *not* have perfect tenses:  only infinitive, past, present, and future.  But we can approximate the perfect tenses with some (slightly awkward) grammar constructions.

> She will have gone into the home, leaving her shoes.
>
> She had gone into the home and had left her shoes.

(Sorry, I am stumped creating a present perfect sentence.)